# Question 3 - Section 3.A Linear Algebra Done Right

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble understanding how to even approach the following question (#3 in section 3.A of Linear Algebra Done Right by Axler):

#### Question 3

Suppose $T \in L(F^n, F^m)$. Show that there exist scalars $A_{j,k} \in F$ for $j = 1,...,m$ and $k = 1,....,n$ such that

$$
T(x_1,...,x_n) = (A_{1,1}x_1 + ... + A_{1,n}x_n,..., A_{m,1}x_1 + ... + A_{m,n}x_n)
$$

for every $(x_1,...,x_n) \in F^n$

My first issue is that I do not understand what there is to prove? Why wouldn't the scalars exist? The formula for the mapping is right there?

Comment: you need to prove it, you cannot assume that it just exists by faith. Hint: $(x_1,x_2,\ldots ,x_n)=x_1 e_1+x_2e_2+\ldots +x_ne_n$ for some basis $e_1,\ldots ,e_n$ of $F^n$. The same happens for $F^m$, now use the linearity of $T$

Comment: @Masacroso why couldn't I just say - the linear map $T$ is defined as follows: $T(x_1,...,x_n) = (A_{1,1}x_1 +...+ A_{1,n}x_n, ... , A_{m,1}x_1 +...+ A_{m,n}x_n)$ for $(x_1,...,x_n) \in F$ and $A_{i,j} \in F$. I just don't understand how these scalars wouldn't exist, I'm defining the linear map to be in terms of these scalars.

Comment: In answer to the comment above: You do not get to pick the linear map $T$. In other words, $T$ is given to you with the property that it is a linear map from $\mathbf{F}^n$ to $\mathbf{F}^m$; you do not get to define $T$. You do get to say how the scalars $A_{j,k}$ are chosen (the choice should depend upon $T$), and then you have to show that the desired equation connecting the $A_{j,k}$ and $T$ holds.

Comment: @SheldonAxler thank you - that clears up my confusion!